# Connection dropped in a lan with multiple servers with 2 interfaces on 2 different subnets

Tags: networking

The problem is as follows:

- we have multiple windows 2008 servers that have 2 interfaces, one on one subnet (ex: 192.168.10.x) and the other on another subnet (ex: 192.168.11.x)
- on each server we have multiple services that communicate with other services (tcp) on other machines.
- the services are all binded on one interface (ex: 10.x)
- the problem is the sometimes (5% of all cases) the connections are timedout. After some researching, it seems that the return messages do not get back to the caller. Using only one switch everything seems to work fine. We speculate that what happens is due to the return message coming on the other interface then the one that started the call and the packets are dropped, thus the call timing out.
- is this a correct assumption? and if so is there a way to solve the problem by keeping both switches on ?

Ty in advance.

Comment: what benefit are you getting by dual-homing your servers?

Comment: I do not know the answer to this questions as this architecture is not done by me, but there are distinct vpns on the 2 subnets, also there is some redundancy schema for it .. my problem relies with why this is happening ..